# How to put anise code in a string(there is single " and ' in ascii code)?

Tags: c++, xcode, ascii

Here is the part:

```
const string{ !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~};
```

With a `"` and `'`, the complier thinks is an another string.

Comment: Please [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking a question.

Comment: and then, read about [Escape sequences](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape)

Comment: Do you know how to *escape* certain characters in string literals? Like for example newline when printing strings? Think about that for a while.

Comment: It's not working!! It keeps thinking it is another string even if i put / before "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu dont need to put asci code in your program. The compiler can do it for you. You can easily convert a char to an int or the other way around